# Javascript addClass removeClass not working as desired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on the icon, I want it to be switched on/off.

In my html file I have:

```
<div class="startSharing"></div>
```

And in my js:

```
$('.startSharing').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('startSharing');
    $(this).addClass('stopSharing');
});

$('.stopSharing').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('stopSharing');
    $(this).addClass('startSharing');
});
```

It works fine when switching from on to off - but I don't understand why it still goes into "startSharing" section when it is turned off.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you're setting the handlers to the particular elements. Once they're set - they're set, regardless of the selector changing.

You could just define it on the `.startSharing` element, if they all start like that. Then, you could use `.toggleClass()` to easily switch them on/off:

```
$('.startSharing').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('startSharing stopSharing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also delegate the click event like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.startSharing', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('startSharing').addClass('stopSharing');
});

$('body').on('click', '.stopSharing', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('stopSharing').addClass('startSharing');
});
```

Doing it this way will also allow dynamically-generated to trigger events. In your case, `.stopSharing` was generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

use event delegation

```js
$('#container').on('click',".startSharing,.stopSharing",function(){
  
    $(this).toggleClass('startSharing').toggleClass('stopSharing');
  
});
```

```css
#container div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.startSharing {
  background-color: green;
}

.startSharing::after {
  content: "start sharing";
}

.stopSharing {
  background-color: red;
}

.stopSharing::after {
  content: "stop sharing";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
  <div class="startSharing"></div>  
</div>
```